# Tkinter root window not coming up

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my program i have tried to get a Tk window to come up yet it does not come up.
I have called my window root and i have put in an event loop, yet it still does
show. I have looked all over the internet for a solution but it appers to cease
to exist.

This is a code snippet from the beggining of the program:

```
def NumberGuessingGame():

    z       = 0
    b       = True
    h       = 0
    name    = 1
    root    = Tk()
    frame1  = Frame( root, width = 400, height = 400 )

    credits = Label( frame1, text = 'NumberGuessingGame.\nAuthor: ***********\nVersion: 6.0', fg = 'red' )
    credits.grid(row = 0)
```

and this is the code snippet from the end of the program:

```
v2 = True

while v2 == True:

    v1 = input( 'Would you like to play the game? ' )

    if v1 == 'y' or v1 == 'yes':
        NumberGuessingGame()
        continue

    elif v1 == 'n' or v1 == 'no':
        print( 'The game will now exit.' )
        break

    else:
        print( 'The game will now exit.' )
        break

input( "Press <ENTER> to close program." )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry about some code being outside of the code snippet.

Comment: Do you know how to mark up a block of text? Select it, then click the `{}` button

Comment: Before posting, you should cut or comment out statements until you get a minimal example that exhibits the problem.  If that does not reveal the cause, and it often does, post that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A: your code never gets into `.mainloop()`

your code-logic preceding the **`root.mainloop()`** fortunately prevents from entering the Tkinter GUI

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that all of my Tkinter stuff is within a function and the root.mainloop() is outside of the function.

Answer (score -1):

you need contructor like so:

```
def __init__(root):
```

this makes your code be able to run and call `root.mainloop()` to make a tk window